# Disable copy & paste in razor

Tags: c#, razor

Is there a way to disable copying data from a table in my view? I have a razor page which has a table and I populate it with data but I am trying to disable the option for user to copy the data.

```
@page "/products"

@attribute [Authorize]

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IViewProductsByNameUseCase ViewProductsByNameUseCase

<h3>Product List</h3>
<br/>

<ViewProductsComponent OnSearchProducts="OnSearchProducts"></ViewProductsComponent>

@if (listProducts != null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Home place</th>
                <th>Expiration</th>
                <th>Phone number</th>
                <th>Tea</th>
                <th>Local</th>
                <th>App</th>
                <th>Company /Lease</th>
                <th>Road time</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var product in this.listProducts)
            {
                <ProductItemComponent 
                    Product="product"
                    OnProductDeleted="OnProductDeleted"></ProductItemComponent>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>    
}
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddProduct">Add Product</button>
```

[image]

I selected the product and I can easily copy it. Can copying be somehow disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following JS functions to handle this:

```
<script>

    if (document.layers) {
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
        document.onmousedown = clickNS4;
    }
    else if (document.all && !document.getElementById) {
        document.onmousedown = clickIE4;
    }

    $('body').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("selectstart", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("dragstart", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("drop", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $(document).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey == true && event.which == '86') {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode === 83 || event.keyCode === 65)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 80) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("body").addClass('unselectable');
</script>
```

And your `unselectable` class will look like:

```
.unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

The above `script` and `css` will disable copying and other aspects. You can tailor them as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to disable copying data from a table in my view?

No.

You cannot DRM HTML.

You cannot control how web-browsers display or interact with HTML.

Otherwise, how else could AdBlockers work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't completely prevent it. But you can make copying a little more difficult. For this, you can use JavaScript code that prevents using right-click, double-click, and keyboard shortcuts.